# ¿Como hacer un select de paises con PHP?

Tags: php, html

Hola buenas tardes estoy haciendo este código para seleccionar un país Pero el problema está que si seleccionó un pais pero me da el ultimo de la lista como puede hacer que muestre el que quiero

```
function pais ($dato, $name, $select, $tipo){
//--    
    $my_pais = array(
        'de'        => 'Alemania',
        'mx'        => 'Mexico',
        'us'        => 'Estados Unidos',        
    );
//--    
    if ($select){
        echo "<select class=\"height_input data_input_two input__settings\" name=\"".$name."\" id=\"Language\">";
                    foreach ($my_pais AS $my_psais) {
                        echo '<option value="'.$my_psais.'" selected>'.$my_psais.'</option>';

                    }
        echo "</select>";
    }   
//--    
    if ($select){
        //-- 
    }else{
        return str_replace( array_keys($my_pais), array_values($my_pais), $dato);
    }
}

echo pais('mx', 'pais', true, false);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para lograr lo que quieres debes hacer una condición dentro del `foreach()` en el cual estás recorriendo el `array` de países, la condición debe validar que la variable `$dato` que recibe la función sea igual al `$key` del país para poderlo marcar como seleccionado:

```
<?php 

function pais ($dato, $name, $select, $tipo){
//--    
    $my_pais = array(
        'de'        => 'Alemania',
        'mx'        => 'Mexico',
        'us'        => 'Estados Unidos',        
    );
//--    
    if ($select){
        echo "<select class=\"height_input data_input_two input__settings\" name=\"".$name."\" id=\"Language\">";
                foreach ($my_pais as $key => $my_psais) {
                    if($key == $dato){
                        echo '<option value="'.$my_psais.'" selected>'.$my_psais.'</option>';
                    }else{
                        echo '<option value="'.$my_psais.'">'.$my_psais.'</option>';
                    }
                }
        echo "</select>";
    }   
//--    
    if ($select){
        //-- 
    }else{
        return str_replace( array_keys($my_pais), array_values($my_pais), $dato);
    }
}

echo pais('de', 'pais', true, false);

?>
```

Comment: se fue champa :´(  - Gracias por la ayuda

Comment: @Shareiv que triste :c, si te sirvió la respuesta te invito a que consideres marcarla como aceptada para que sea de ayuda a futuros desarrolladores, saludos !